# Port 81 for http is redirecting to 80

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, port-forwarding, virtual-host

I have created port 80 and 81 for my Apache. Below is the configuration.

```
Listen 80
Listen 81

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/wp"
    ServerName www.test.tk
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost  *:81>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/pw"
    ServerName www.exampl.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The issue is, if I call `www.exampl.com` with port 80, it will redirect to `www.test.tk`. I want it to show the default page of Apache for `www.exampl.com:80` and `IP:80` as well.

How do I do it?

Comment: I believe you want a *:80 block with a ServerName field of www.exampl.com — one can have multiple sites listening over a single port, distinguished only by ServerName

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you just want both hostnames to answer on port 80.
Apache allows you to do that, no redirection is needed. It will just tell the difference by parsing the HTTP host header.

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/wp"
    ServerName www.test.tk
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost  *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/pw"
    ServerName www.exampl.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If you're going to configure your vhosts further it is also recommended that you put them in separate files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Comment: he asked a valid problem, I am also facing same :(